# Onen eating outside sukkah

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, sukkah, sukkot, masechet-sukkah

Is an onen exempt from eating in the sukkah on sukkot? Are they allowed to eat outside the sukkah (sources much appreciated please).

Comment: There is no mourning on Succos

Comment: Jewish law does not permit mourning on Yom Tov.  I don't see why people who had a recent loss should be treated differently relative to the sukkah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh Deah 341:1 writes that there is no aninus on shabbos or yom tov(except marital relations which is forbidden). However, if they would go near the techum towards the end of shabbos ,or yom tov to help prepare for the meis then full aninus applies once they start to travel to the techum .

So in a case of sukkos(yom tov) they would be obligated to eat in the sukkah unless they were on their way to prepare for the meis(להחשיך על התחום).

However ,on chol hamoed aninus would apply as the Shulchan Aruch 399:2 notes.

There is an interesting machlokes when it comes to sukkah on chol hamoed whether an onen needs to sit in a sukka or not. One tzad to say one is obligated is to say that not sitting in a sukka is violating a commandment which an onen is obligated in. The Mishna Berura(640:31) brings the Pri Megadim(possibly obligated) and the Bikurei Yaakov(patur from sukkah) on this machlokes.

Text of Shulchan Aruch:

ובשבת ויו"ט אוכל בשר ושותה יין (אם ירצה) (רבינו יונה פ' מי שמתו) ומברך וחייב בכל המצות חוץ מבתשמיש המטה שאסור בו (ומותר לילך לבית הכנסת בשבת ואף בחול אין בו איסור רק מאחר שאסור להתפלל מה יעשה שם) (כל בו) ואם צריך להחשיך על התחום כדי לעסוק בצרכי המת חל עליו אנינות ליאסר בכולן משעה שמתחיל ללכת כדי להחשיך על התחום

Text of Shulchan Aruch 399:2

הַקוֹבֵר מֵתוֹ בָּרֶגֶל בְּחֹל הַמּוֹעֵד, נֹהַג דִּין אֲנִינוּת כָּל זְמַן שֶׁלֹּא נִקְבַּר; וּלְאַחַר שֶׁנִּקְבַּר, נוֹהֵג דְּבָרִים שֶׁבְּצִנְעָא